# Align text in AccordionSummary to the right?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion, text-alignment, text-align

I'm working with the Accordion component from Material-UI (https://material-ui.com/api/expansion-panel-summary/). It seems like by default, regardless of what I do, the text (specifically the word 'Filter' which appears in `AccordionSummary`) is aligned to the left. How can I change this so it aligned to the right?

```
<Accordion>
 <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<FilterListIcon style={{color: 'white'}} />}
                    style={{backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white', textAlign: "right"}}> 
                    Filter
 </AccordionSummary>
  <AccordionDetails style={{backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white'}}>
         //Some details here
  </AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AccordionSummary` component primarily uses `flex` containers so `textAlign` won't do that work for you. You can use `justifyContent` instead. You may target the `content` rule name to specifically target the content (i.e., your Filter text) of AccordionSummary

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customAccordionSummary: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }
})

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Accordion>
      <AccordionSummary
        classes={{ content: classes.customAccordionSummary }}
        ...
```